# Creating Dictionary from list

Tags: c#

I want to prepare a dictionary from xml file nested with list because as have multiple values against one key.
 below code I am using for this -

```
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfVariation; i++)
    {
        SingleVariationDom.LoadXml(VariationSet[i].OuterXml);
        XmlNodeList CASInputParam = SingleVariationDom.GetElementsByTagName("CASInputParam");
        string Attr = null;
         ObjList.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < CASInputParam.Count; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                var NonTabularValueElement = SingleVariationDom.GetElementsByTagName("CASInputParam")[0];
                Attr = NonTabularValueElement.Attributes["MailParam"].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                var NonTabularValueElement = SingleVariationDom.GetElementsByTagName("CASInputParam")[j];
                string Attribut = NonTabularValueElement.Attributes["MailParam"].Value;
                ObjList.Add(Attribut);
            }
        }

        ObjParentDiction.Add(Attr, ObjList);

    }
```

When I am clearing the list object `ObjList` its clearing the values of dictionary in which I have already added values as a list.

Please suggest to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

> When I am clearing the list object ObjList its clearing the values of dictionary in which I have already added values as a list.

This is because you keep adding the same instance. Replace

```
  ObjList.Clear();
```

with

```
 ObjList = new List ...
```

to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`ObjList` is the same list in every iteration of the loop.

You want to create a different instance for each iteration by writing `new List<string>()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

```
ObjParentDiction.Add(Attr, ObjList);
```

to:

```
ObjParentDiction.Add(Attr, ObjList.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create an instance of the list of object with
ObjList = new List() and ObjList.Clear() outside of the outerloop. 
then each time before entering the loop list of object will be cleared and 
after entering into the loop object will be repopulated again.

thanks.
```